# Array of 2d arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays

My question is difficult to describe, and I have two tables containing lots of numbers respectively; for one table, I search format through index

```
table1   index format  
        +------+----+                        
        |0~19  |  0 |
        |      |    |
        +------+----+
        |20~29 |  1 |
        |      |    |
        +------+----+
        |30~39 |  2 |
        |      |    |
        +------+----+

table2  index  resource(f,t0,t1,t2)  
                  0           1        2         3 (configure type)
        +----+-----------+---------+---------+                      
        |0   | (0,1,0,2) |(0,1,0,1)|(0,1,0,0)|
        +----+-----------+---------+---------+
        |1   | (0,2,0,2) |(0,2,0,1)|(0,2,0,0)|
        +----+-----------+---------+---------+
        |--  | (0,0,1,2) |(0,0,1,1)|(1,0,0,0)|
        +----+-----------+---------+---------+
        |19  | (0,0,0,0) |(0,0,0,0)|(0,0,1,1)|
        +----+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
        |--  | (0,0,0,2) |(0,0,0,1)|(0,0,1,0)|(0,2,1,0)|
        +----+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
        |29  | (0,1,0,2) |(0,1,0,1)|(0,1,0,1)|(0,1,0,1)|
        +----+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Hopefully,the following code snippet can make me understood,

```
typedef struct my_struct {
    int f;
    int t0;
    int t1;
    int t2;
} my_struct;

// for index 0 ~ 19, the following is code snippet
    my_struct format0[2][3] = {
        {{0, 1, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 0, 1},{0, 1, 0, 0}}, // index 0
        {{0, 2, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 0, 1},{0, 2, 0, 0}}  // index 1
    };

// for index 20 ~ 29, the following is code snippet    
my_struct format1[1][4] = {
    {{0,0,0,2},{0,0,0,1},{0,0,1,0},{0,2,1,0}} // index 20
};
```

I have multiple 2d arrays containing resources grouped by `format`, each has different dimensions for different `format`, rowed by `index`, coled by `configure type` like 0,1,2..6, so I want to put them into another 1d array in order to look up easily through index, and get resource finally, but I don't know how.

I have tried the following but failed:

```
my_struct* group[] = {
    format0,
    format1
};
```

then using `group[0]`, I can get `format0`, but I find it forgot its `[1][2]` which I need to know, so I am wondering there is some solution help me do that?

Comment: your initialization of format0 is wrong, my_struct format0[1][2] = {{0, 1}};

Comment: How do you have the dimensions of each array? I mean where do you get them from?

Comment: hi TAMER, I have a table hold a lot of numbers, they have inner relations to each other, the dimensions is got from that table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have each the arrays dimensions in two arrays `d1` (for the number of rows) and `d2` (for the number of columns), you can do this:

```
struct foo {
    my_struct** arr;
    int dim1;
            int dim2;
};

foo group[dimension] = {
    {format0,d1[0],d2[0]},
    {format1,d1[1],d2[1]},
};
```

Thus you keep the array's dimension close, and can use them like this for example:

```
for (int i = 0;i<dimension;i++)
{
    for(int j = 0;j<group[i].dim1;j++)
    {
        for (int k=0;k<group[i].dim2;k++)
        {
            group[i].arr[j][k]; // do something with it!
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise if you don't have the dimensions in `d1`, `d2` and `dimension`, it's not possible to know them later after the arrays are define, and thus you won't be able to search (as you say you want to do).

Comment: Hi, TAMER, thanks for your reply; I also thought to define another struct to hold all of that I need, your answer confirms my idea.

Comment: You won't be able to access arr[j][k] like that, it is just a pointer. You will need a function to calculate the linear index into arr.

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes I can, arrays are in fact pointers, you can always use the `[ ]` operator with pointers.

Comment: True, and since you edited it to be my_struct **, now you can access arr[][]> However, now the initialization won't work, since it will treat format0 as an array of pointers, which it is not.

Comment: True, but I'm assuming that `format0, format1, etc..` are also pointers because he should be reading the dimensions and thus dynamically allocating these arrays, otherwise the program seems useless.

Comment: @Mr.TAMER: To save CPU time, I can and have to define my array as static instead of dynamically allocating those arrays, does your solution apply as well?

Answer (score 0):

Your struct doesn't seem to contain much in the way of actual arrays/matrices.

I'd use something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  size_t width, height;
  int    *data;
} Matrix2D;
```

then define a function to initialize an instance:

```
int matrix2d_new(Matrix2D *out, size_t width, size_t height)
{
  if(out == NULL || width == 0 || height == 0)
    return 0;
  if((out->data = malloc(width * height * sizeof *out->data)) != NULL)
  {
    out->width = width;
    out->height = height;
    memset(out->data, 0, width * height * sizeof *out->data);
  }
  return out != NULL;
}
```

then you can build an array trivially:

```
Matrix2D matrices[3];
matrix2d_new(&matrices[0], 12, 34);
matrix2d_new(&matrices[1], 40, 50);
matrix2d_new(&matrices[2], 20, 50);
```

Error-checking is ignored, but must of course be considered when dealing with dynamic memory.

Answer (score 0):

By treating group as an array of pointers you lose the ability to access the pointers as 2D arrays.

One option is to use only 1D arrays:

```
my_struct format00[3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
my_struct format01[3] = {{10,20,30}, {40,50,60}, {70,80,90}};

my_struct *format0[2] = {format00, format01};
my_struct *format1[2] = {format10, format11};

my_struct **group[] = {format0, format1};

my_struct a = group[0][0][1];  // {4,5,6}
```

Of course, this is much less convenient to initialize.

Comment: One of the other suggestions about using a struct for your matrices rather than simple arrays is certainly safer and preferred.

Comment: thanks, you mean array will decay into pointers and lose its dimensions when I put them into another array as element, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you’re actually using C++ and not C, then you can use a more C++-centric solution, with `std::vector` and C++11 initialiser lists:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;

typedef struct my_struct {
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
} my_struct;

typedef vector<vector<my_struct>> Matrix;

Matrix format0 {
    {{0, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}
};

Matrix format1 {
    {{0, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}},
    {{3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}}
};

vector<Matrix*> groups { &format0, &format1 };

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for (auto i = groups.begin(); i != groups.end(); ++i)
        cout << (**i).size() << 'x' << (**i)[0].size() << '\n';
}
```

But this is still unusual, and I’m not sure what problem you’re really trying to solve. If what you need is a proper `Matrix` class, then you should write one so you can stop dealing with raw arrays and focus on what you really want to do.